# Is 'over' used correctly here?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to say that the number of Xs is more than 10 times the nubmer of Ys, say, there are 10 Ys and 103 Xs. Can I say it the way below?

> Xs outnumber Ys ten times over.

If not, how can I put it?

Comment: the phrasing is correct. You could also say "there are ten times as many Xs as Ys" or "X outnumbers Y by an order of magnitude"

Comment: @mstorkson I want to say Xs are more than 10 times more than Ys, e.g. Xs 103 Ys 10, not that Xs are 10 times Ys, that is Xs 100 Ys 10.

Comment: "times over" works for that, or you can say "there are more than ten times as many" or "x outnumbers y by more than an order of magnitude"

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can say that:

> X is more than ten times bigger than Y.

Or:

> X is more than ten times greater than Y.

---

I think when you want to say that something outnumbers something else by a certain amount, you typically would want to use the preposition *by*:

> Xs outnumber Ys by more than ten times.

Comment: What if I like to use 'outnumber'?

Comment: Xs outnumber Ys by more than ten to one .